# Passing to a eventhandler external argument in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm trying to create an object to manage dragging elements in jquery using a javascript object, but it doesn't work.

```
var elementDragged = 
{   clicked :  false,
    element :  $("div"),
    mouseUp :  function() {this.clicked = false;},
    mouseDown : function() {this.clicked = true;},
    mouseMove : function(element, clicked){
                return function(event) {
                            if(clicked)
                            { 
                             element.css({left: event.pageX-element.width()/2, top: event.pageY-element.height()/2});
                            }
                            }}(this.element, this.clicked),                 
    start : function(){ this.element.on({
            mouseup: this.mouseUp,
            mousedown: this.mouseDown,
            mousemove: this.mouseMove
    })}
};

elementDragged.start();
```

The firefox browser console doesn't tell me anything.
Can anyone help me to understand how put the proprierties clicked and element into the handler to mousemove proprerty?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, but now it works well with div whereas I have problem with input and img:

```
var elementDragged = 
{   
clicked :  {status :  false},
element :  $("input"),              
start : function(){ this.element.on({
                mouseup: function(clicked) {
                             return  function() {clicked.status = false;}
                         }(this.clicked),

                mousedown: function(clicked) {
                             return  function() {clicked.status = true;}
                         }(this.clicked),

                mousemove: function(element, clicked){
                             return function(event) {
                                if(clicked.status)
                                { xValue = event.pageX-element.width()/2;
                                  yValue = event.pageY-element.height()/2;
                                 element.css({left: xValue, top: yValue});
                                }
                          }}(this.element, this.clicked)
    })}
};

elementDragged.start();
```

Any idea about this behavoiur?